# Processing JSON of arrays in array with jq

Tags: json, jq

Environment: JQ 1.5, Windows 64-bit.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "unique": 1924,
  "coordinates": [
    {
      "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:01.683",
      "xyz": [
        {
          "z": 4,
          "y": 2,
          "x": 1,
          "id": 99
        },
        {
          "z": 9,
          "y": 9,
          "x": 8,
          "id": 100
        },
        {
          "z": 9,
          "y": 6,
          "x": 10,
          "id": 101
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:02.790",
      "xyz": [
        {
          "z": 0,
          "y": 3,
          "x": 7,
          "id": 99
        },
        {
          "z": 4,
          "y": 6,
          "x": 2,
          "id": 100
        },
        {
          "z": 2,
          "y": 9,
          "x": 51,
          "id": 101
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And would like to convert it into this CSV format with jq:

```
unique,time,id,x,y,z
1924,"2015-01-25T00:00:01.683",99,1,2,4
1924,"2015-01-25T00:00:01.683",100,8,9,9
```

(and so on)

I tried a few things, such as:

```
jq -r '{unique: .unique, coordinates: .coordinates[].xyz[] | [.id, .x, .y, .z], time: .coordinates.[].time} | flatten | @csv'
```

which gave me my desired JSON, but multiplied for every id, x, y, and z (i.e. each unique line appears four times - one each for id, x, y, z).

Assigning a number to the array, such as

```
jq -r '{unique: .unique, coordinates: .coordinates[0].xyz[] | [.id, .x, .y, .z], time: .coordinates.[0].time} | flatten | @csv'
```

gives me the first index of the `coordinates` array, but I'd like all of them, naturally.

Comment: For what language? Javascript?

Comment: With jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Mmm. Requiring a very recent build, there; I'm still on 1.4. But then, such is the way of shiny features...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First step would be to flatten down the results to rows.

```
[{ unique } + (.coordinates[] | { time } + .xyz[])]
```

This would yield an array of objects per row:

```
[
  {
    "unique": 1924,
    "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:01.683",
    "id": 99,
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2,
    "z": 4
  },
  {
    "unique": 1924,
    "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:01.683",
    "id": 100,
    "x": 8,
    "y": 9,
    "z": 9
  },
  {
    "unique": 1924,
    "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:01.683",
    "id": 101,
    "x": 10,
    "y": 6,
    "z": 9
  },
  {
    "unique": 1924,
    "time": "2015-01-25T00:00:02.790",
    "id": 99,
    "x": 7,
    "y": 3,
    "z": 0
  },
  ...
]
```

Then it's just a matter of converting this to csv rows.

```
["unique","time","id","x","y","z"] as $fields | $fields, (.[] | [.[$fields[]]]) | @csv
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been using the flatten / @csv paradigm for previous commands - is your method to convert to CSV faster/more efficient, would you say?

Comment: I don't think `flatten` would really work here. It's meant to flatten arrays of arrays, not objects. And you wouldn't want to use it because flattening an object will yield the values. You'll lose the associated keys and ordering is not guaranteed. You would need to convert to other intermediate forms to utilize that better. The approach I took here is more direct so I would expect it to be relatively faster than trying to get it to work with flatten.